# Rails constants editable by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, persistence, constants, static-variables, user-defined

I need to store semi-constants :

- Static variables (just one of each per application)
- Used in many places (somewhat as templates)
- Some SuperUsers can edit them (frontend form to edit them)
- Persistence (must keep their value even with a serverrestart)
- Different types (DateTime, String, Float, Integer, etc.)

Is there a nice way to do that ? (We're talking about just ~20 constants)

There is the solution of 1 table with as many columns as constants. Ugly.
Our old application used to have a table "Constants" where one constant = one entry. But I think this is ugly as well because they had one "column" per type of constant

(I'm talking about columns as for now my app is using ActiveRecord, but we might change to mongoid later. Yet it would pose the same problem of having one table with just one entry)

Comment: hey, did you have a moment to check this out? will it work with Mongoid?

Comment: Sorry, I just added Mongoid (so now I have a temporary hybrid ActiveRecord/Mongoid install) but it brought its set of problems, and I havent had time to check yet if the gem was mongoid compatible. I'll let you know later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This gem](https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached) is an answer to your needs.

```
gem "rails-settings-cached"
```

It allows you to easily define any settings/constants whatever like so:

```
Setting.admin_password = 'supersecret'
Setting.date_format    = '%m %d, %Y'
Setting.cocktails      = ['Martini', 'Screwdriver', 'White Russian']
Setting.foo            = 123
Setting.credentials    = { :username => 'tom', :password => 'secret' }
```

Due to last comments, here is the [link to same gem for Mongoid](http://github.com/marten/mongoid-app_settings).

Comment: This gem uses ActiveRecord. So if I plan to migrate from ActiveRecord to Mongoid documents I'm screwed ?
Otherwise, yes I would need something like this.

Comment: I will be honest - I am of no help in questions ActiveRecord/Mongoid, so this on your shoulders now to find out if it will work with mongoid (the fastest way would be just to send to gem author an email with short question)

Comment: If you edit your answer to include a link to https://github.com/marten/mongoid-app_settings I'll accept it.
(It's a similar gem but for Mongoid)